# Problem with Hyperref. Only shows text and not any clickable link

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

Hi I am using TeXmaker (version 4.4.1 (compiled with Qt 5.4.2 and Poppler 0.38.0)) to compile LaTeX. I am facing problem with hyperlinks. None of my hyperlinks are *clickable*. They don't even follow the format I have specified in the `hypersetup` arguments.

I have written the following script:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

\href{url address}{sample text}

\end{document}
```

This does print the **sample text** but it just appears as text.

Not sure what's the problem or how to debug.

**EDIT:** I have used to `documentclass` line. Didn't put it here, sorry. Here is the **code before \hyperref**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

**EDIT 2** :I compile PDFLaTeX. Then use Document Veiwer (Ubuntu 16.04) to view PDFs. I used Adobe Acrobat Reader with *WINE* too. Same problem persists with hyperlink.

Comment: Welcome, as there is no documentclass line, your example cannot work.

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: Do you maybe specify `draft` as one of the options passed to the document class?

Answer (score 5):

Based on your given code you need to comment class option `draft` to get hyperlinks.

Please see the manual for package `hyperref` (`texdoc hyperref` -- `manual.pdf`):

[image: manual hyperref]

Please see the follwowing MWE (important code changing marked with `<=======`)

```
\documentclass[%
  12pt,
  a4paper,
% draft     % <=========================================================
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=cyan,
}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

\href{url address}{sample text}

\end{document}
```

with the following resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]